# how to use command Select-String to grep two string, use the regex `(str1|str2)`

Tags: powershell

Q1: How to get the shortest match result in Select-String?

for the command parameter:

```
-source_file "proccess.log" -regex "D\:\\.*\.'(zip|7z|rar)'"
```

with the power shell file:

```
    param(
    # Enter Source File Path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$source_file,
    # regex
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$regex
    )

    $result3=Get-Content -Path $source_file |Select-String -Pattern "$regex"|foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
    Write-Output $result3
```

it always outputs the longest matching strings likes `D:\test.zip D:\string1.zip" " D:\string2.rar`
how could i get the output result like:

```
D:\test.zip
D:\string1.zip
D:\string2.rar
```

then i could handle the exception condition.

## Resolve Problem 1:

```
-source_file "proccess.log" -AllMatches -regex "D\:\\.*?\.'(zip|7z|rar)'"
```

thanks for the answer from @AdminOfThings !

P.s. question 2 is: why using the parentheses in the regex have to closure by the apostrophe?  Regex is written by guess...and it works. but i don't know whyyyy.

Comment: `.*` is greedy where `.*?` is lazy matching.

Comment: thanks for your advice. in this case, i try 
`-source_file "proccess.log" -regex "D\:\\.*?\.'(zip|7z|rar)'"`
and just get the result:
`D:\test.zip`

Comment: I think i found the answer.... just add the parameter `-AllMatches`